# Microsoft project assigning IDs to specific rows only

Tags: microsoft-project-2010, gantt

I've created a microsoft project Gantt chart with lots of rows. The rows are made up of main topics and related tasks beneath these. I want to attach an ID number to only those sub task rows so that it does not reference the main topic or give it an id - is this possible? At the moment it's defaulting to assign every row an id number which I can't amend manually? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but Project automatically assigns task IDs to all tasks in a project.  You can certainly add a spare text field and manually enter any values you wish, but the Task IDs are created by Project and used to reference tasks in Predecessor and Successor fields.

You can hide the ID column if needed.